# How to remove space between input field and containing div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I have this on my page[image]

and this code

```
 <div class="col-md-9 .list-title-input" style="border:1px solid red;" >
    <?= $form->field($model, 'product_title')->textInput([  ]); ?>

 </div>
```

How can i remove the bottom space between the text input field and the containing div to get Draft saved placed immediately after the Div

I added css to control the input like this

```
.list-title-input input{
width:100%;
height:30px;
position: relative;
border-radius: 2px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
background: #ffffff;


}
```

and i didn't add margin to the input, the input field was generated my yi2 active form so i guess the problem is there because if i don't use active form everything is fine
i hope someone can help me with this

i think the problem is with automatically generated input field when i inspect the element i found that a div with class form-group was added so does bootstrap form-group has margin- button and if it does how can i remove this. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin to the input field is usually applied via `.form-group` class i.e

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Which is applied to the wrapper to the input field.

```
<div class="form-group field-user-name required">
<label class="control-label" for="user-name">Name</label>
<input id="user-name" class="form-control" name="User[name]" maxlength="255" type="text">
<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

You can change this class while you are initiating the filed in _form.php

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

So, the file code for your desired class will be:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name', ['options' => ['class' => 'MY-CLASS-WITH-NO-MARGIN']])->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

then output will be:

```
<div class="MY-CLASS-WITH-NO-MARGIN field-user-name required">
<label class="control-label" for="user-name">Name</label>
<input id="user-name" class="form-control" name="User[name]" maxlength="255" type="text">
<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

So in this way you can control the behavior for your wrapper div.

Answer (score 1):

Could not reproduce your issue, so my assumption is you have some CSS that defines margin of your `input` field. You can do this to override that margin value.

```css
.no-margin {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-9" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <input type="text" class="no-margin" />
</div>
```

**UPDATED:**

If you need to override the form-group class, simply add another class to your element that uses that class, like this:

CSS:

```
.form-group.no-padding {
 padding: 0 !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group no-padding">
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, i just updated my question maybe u can see it again, i think the problem is with automatically generated input field when  i inspect the element i found that a div with class form-group was added so does bootstrap form-group has margin- button and if it does how can i remove this. thanks

Comment: Still cannot reproduce the problem. Not a related issue but you need to remove the dot when you use the CSS class in your DIV element <div class="col-md-9 .list-title-input"...

Comment: Thanks i found the problem to be form-group class, using yii2 active form created a input field with class="form-group", now form group has a margin-bottom, is there a way i can remove this margin-buttom without having to edit the main bootstrap code??

Comment: Well, you can override the form-group class like in the updated answer (sorry because I cannot format the code in comment).